# What is "parametric solution" of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I stumbled across the term "parametric solution" in regard to differential equations, but couldn't find an real definition anywhere.

From my classes I know that an explicit solution to an differential equation can be explicitly written as $y(x)=...$ while an implicit solution can be written as a solution to an equation such as $F(x,y(x))=0$.

But what exactly is meant by "parametric solution"? Is there a rigorous definition or is it just another term for "implicit solution"?

Answer (score 2):

I would think it is a solution of the form $x=\xi(s)$, $y=\psi(s)$. Then by the chain rule this is a solution of $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ if $\frac{\psi'(s)}{\xi'(s)}=f(\xi(s).\psi(s))$ for all $s$ in some domain interval.

For instance some homogeneous equation $y'(x)=\frac{ax+by}{cx+dy}$ could be separated into a linear system for a parametric solution
$$
\xi'(s)=c\xi(s)+d\psi(s),\\
\psi'(s)=a\xi(s)+b\psi(s),
$$
where now the linear system can be solved as usual via the eigen decomposition.